# Como fazer um formulário php enviar, sem recarregar a página

Tags: php, formulário

Quando eu clico em enviar no formulário, queria que ele validasse os campos, com o PHP, porém que não recarregasse a página.

Estou usando esse codigo:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Contato do site'; 
        $to = 'giovanni@'; 
        $subject = 'Formulário de contato - ';

        $body ="Enviado por: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Menssagem:\n $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Por favor, insira o seu nome';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Por favor, insira um endereço de e-mail válido';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Por favor, insira a sua mensagem';
        }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Obrigado! Entraremos em contato em breve!</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Desculpe, houve um erro ao enviar a sua mensagem. Por favor tente de novo mais tarde.</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap contact form with PHP example">
    <meta name="author" content="BootstrapBay.com">
    <title>Bootstrap Contact Form With PHP Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1 class="page-header text-center">Contact Form Example</h1>
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2">Nome</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Seu Nome" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Seu E-mail" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2">Menssagem</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Sua Mensagem"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <?php echo $result; ?>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Eu costumo deixar em outra página o PHP e chamar pelo action, mas resolvi deixar tudo em uma página para ver se dava certo, mas não deu.

Comment: Boa tarde Giovanni, sabe o que é ajax?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sei, mas eu me daria uns 30% de noção sobre ajax. Mas pode falar ai Guilherme, que eu corro atrás de saber!!

Comment: Para fazer a validação na mesma pagina é preciso que a validação seja feita por javascript sem necessariamente enviar os dados. Para isso há plugins que fazer a tarefa de validação, eu uso bastante o jquery validate -> [http://jqueryvalidation.org/](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) que é muito bom. Da uma olhada nele.

Comment: Ajax não faz refresh à pagina como @GuilhermeNascimento disse